# How to add deleted user in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, windows-server

I have set up sql server 2008 in windows server 2008 r2 and it works fine. However, I have deleted the my user from logins in the sql server accidentally and now I cannot find a way to log in to the sql server and I believe I did not set up any other user well. Think of it as I just installed and removed the user.

Is there anyway that I can add an account?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below alternatives:

1. If you installed SQL Server then you will be having "`sa`" - if mixed mode authentication is enabled. You can use "`sa`" account to create a login and map that login to a database.
2. Alternatively, you can use "`DAC`" (if you have enabled it as a part of post installation step).
3. By default, `BUILTIN\Administrators` has access to sql server 2008 instance. If you are part of `BUILTIN\Administrators` group then you will have access.
4. Last resort : [Recover access to a SQL Server instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/) by Aaron Bertrand wherein he shows how to use `PsExec` to get into sql server.

Once you gain access to sql server, then create a login and map that login to a database.

Make sure to **NOT** delete it again :-)

Comment: Best part of the answer :"Make sure to NOT delete it again" :)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a MSDN document that explains how to start the SQL service in single user mode that will allow you to connect as part of the sysadmin built in role to add users back in.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.100).aspx

The 2008 version doesn't have as much detail as the 2014 version but you should be able to use reference both versions to get your accounts back in.